# Smart Contract Invocation using tezos-client and RPC requests failed

Tags: node, smart-contracts, tezos-client

**Network: Babylonnet test network**

> **Network Version**:
>    {
>       "chain_name": "TEZOS_ALPHANET_BABYLON_2019-09-27T07:43:32Z",
>       "distributed_db_version": 0, "p2p_version": 0
>     }

**Case**: I'm trying to invoke a smart contract with a suit of RPC requests via the binary tezos-client the command-line client, to do so here is a list of operation and requests:

```
  // RPC request: Get Counter
  let counter = await getCounter();
  // RPC request: Get Manager Key
  const managerKey = await getManagerKey();
  // RPC request: Get Protocol
  const protocol = await getProtocol();
  // RPC request: Get Blockhash
  const blockHash = await getBlockHash();
  // RPC request: Get ChainID
  const chainId = await getChainID();
  // Increment the Counter
  counter = parseInt(counter.data, 10) + 1;
  // Forge an operation returning the unsigned bytes
  const forgeOperationResult = await forgeOperation(
    blockHash.data,
    chainId.data,
    counter.toString()
  );
  // Sign Forge Result with tezos-client
  const signatureExecution = await signOperation(forgeOperationResult.data);
  const operationBytes = signatureExecution.split(" ")[1].split("\n")[0];
  // Decode the signature
  const signatureBS58 = bs58.decode(operationBytes.split("\n")[0]);
  const signatureBytes = signatureBS58
    .toString("hex")
    .substring(10, signatureBS58.toString("hex").length - 8);

  // We get finally the data ready to be injected
  const injectionReady = forgeOperationResult.data.concat(signatureBytes);

  // Run an operation without signature checks
  const runOperationResult = await runOperation(
    blockHash.data,
    counter.toString(),
    operationBytes,
    chainId.data
  );

  // Simulate the validation of an operation
  const preapplyOperationResult = await preapplyOperation(
    protocol.data.protocol,
    blockHash.data,
    counter.toString(),
    operationBytes
  );

  /**
  Inject an operation in node and broadcast it. Returns the ID of the 
  operation. The `signedOperationContents` should be constructed using a 
  contextual RPCs from the latest block and signed by the client. 
  */
  const injectionResult = await curlOperation(injectionReady);

  const transactionHash = injectionResult.substring(
    1,
    injectionResult.length - 2
  );

  await curlConfirmation(transactionHash, blockHash.data);
```

And I got after launching this script a transaction hash just like:

> opA4Kf3AttQiZwzeoUzEaFUuvjuoRWJGZ9j1rSg73rkjrkv3uit

But the operation isn't included in any block and I can't find it in the block exlorers and the smart contracts stroage is never changed even after getting a success result when I simulated the transaction with the **Preapply** endpoint.
As result from confirmation process I got the error:

> Fatal error:
>     The operation opA4Kf3AttQiZwzeoUzEaFUuvjuoRWJGZ9j1rSg73rkjrkv3uit is outdated and may never be included in the chain.
>     We recommand to use an external block explorer.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**: The problem was with the storage_limit/gas_limit/fee fields in the Forge request.